# How to make qt not omit methods?

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, mingw, qmake

I have following Qt project structure:

static library #1

```
public class LibraryClass
{
     public int Test();
}
```

static library #2 (reference to library #1)

```
void SomeMethod()
{
   ...
   x = library1Instance.Test();
   ...
}
```

executable (reference to library #1 and library #2)

```
void SomeOtherMethod()
{
   ...
   library2Instance.SomeMethod();
   ...
}
```

Libraries #1 and library #2 compile without errors. But when I'm trying to compile executable, I got error "undefined reference to LibaryClass::Test()". Which means that libary #1 is linked without LibraryClass::Test() method.

If I create another class in library #1, and make that class reference to LibaryClass::Test() method, everything will compile.

As far as I understood, compiler omits method LibaryClass::Test() because it can found no internal reference to it. So, I should somehow to mark it as method for export or something. How can I do it?

Comment: How exactly do you link the program? The order matters for static libraries: #1 must come after #2 to resolve the dependency.

Comment: How can I check linking order? I'm using Qt Creator. The only place I can found where there's both libarary #1 and #2 is executable.pro file (that is where I reference to those libraries)

Comment: Yes, it seems I should place library#1 references last in the .pro file. Thanks, Mike!

Answer (score 1):

You should make a global definition in a file included in all projects:

```
#if defined(MAKEDLL)
# define MY_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
# define MY_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

In libraries, add this line to `.pro` files:

```
DEFINES   += MAKEDLL
```

In `.pro` of executable, add nothing. Then, in library define `LibraryClass` as

```
public MY_EXPORT class LibraryClass
{
    ...
}
```

For static method:

```
MY_EXPORT void SomeMethod()
{
   ...
   x = library1Instance.Test();
   ...
}
```

In executable, instantiate the class and call the method as usual. The linker will resolve the dependencies if your subprojects (library1, library2, and executable) are built to the same directory.